# In dbt, how do I only rerun models associated with failed tests?

Tags: dbt

I’m doing some local testing using dbt core and trying to figure out how to only rerun models associated with failed tests from the prior dbt build invocation.

I’ve setup a test scenario with 3 models (models a, b, and c). I ran dbt build. The models were built and tests were run. The scenario has a failed `not_null` test, which impacts models a and c.

Now, I want to rerun only the models associated with the failed test (a and c), without having to manually select them.

I tried doing `dbt build --select 1+result:fail` which I found [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/methods#the-result-method). That resulted in

```
Encountered an error:
No comparison run_results
```

I also tried `dbt build –-select result:error+ –-defer -–state ./target` which I found [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/dbt-airflow-spiritual-alignment#rerunning-jobs-from-failure). That resulted in

```
dbt: error: unrecognized arguments: –-select result:error+ –-defer -–state ./target
```

I’m guessing running only models impacted by failed tests relies on `run_results.json` which I see in `./target`. So, I'm thinking I’m missing some kind of configuration step, but I’m having a hard time finding info on how to rerun dbt from the point of failure. Any suggestions or resources for this issue?

Comment: You're absolutely on the right track. Can you confirm that you're on version >= 1.0.0? `dbt debug` or `dbt --version` will tell you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I ended up having some unnoticed em dashes in the second command I tried.
This is what I was after

```
dbt build --select 1+result:fail+ --defer --state ./target
```

Answered in [dbt slack](https://getdbt.slack.com/archives/C2JRRQDTL/p1661473653635799).